# Spring Boot Flyway migrations not executed, SQL files are in JAR

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I have a Spring Boot application using Flyway Migrations. Everything runs fine, from:

- within IntelliJ
- from the terminal on my macbook

With 'fine' I mean, migration files are found, which are placed in src/main/resources and end up in the Spring Boot executable jar.

However, when I run the jar from the commandline on Centos 6.8, Flyway is unable to find the migration files.

Any ideas?

Using Java 8.

Comment: Is there any chance that you are using a different properties (for example, application-prod.yml) when you start the app on the different OS and the paths that flyway needs are different in that profile ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem, I'm facing a similar issue?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to resolve it is to open at your logger the package `org.flywaydb` to loglevel `DEBUG` and retry. For sure you'll find the initial clue.

Good luck